# groovy.lang.MissingMethodException when trying to use viewbinding

Tags: android, gradle, groovy, android-viewbinding

I'm working on a big project and I'm trying to add view binding using two different aproaches:

#### First aproach:

```
buildFeatures {
    viewBinding true
}
```

#### Second aproach:

```
viewBinding {
    enabled true
}
```

On both cases I get a `Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: build_4xgux05b5phesnrai6p6fg7vc.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_4xgux05b5phesnrai6p6fg7vc$_run_closure3) values: [build_4xgux05b5phesnrai6p6fg7vc$_run_closure3@5e534db6]`

I am putting this inside `android { }` on my module:app.

Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Share your android studio and android gradle plugin versions.

Comment: @sdex Android Studio 3.6.1 and gradle com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to increase android gradle plugin version to 3.6.0 (or higher):

```
// Android Gradle Plugin 3.6.0
android {
    viewBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}
```

Or:

```
// Android Gradle Plugin 4.0
android {
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue on my Android Studio, what I did to fix it was this:

Before the

```
android { 
   ...
}
```

I check the plugins fields, i.e:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
    id 'kotlin-kapt' <- this one is when you need to use databinding I think
}
```

For my case to fix this issue I just add the line

```
id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

And all works as expected, hope this answer would be useful for your problem

Answer (score 0):

In my case this seems to have occurred in Android Studio when I added versionName values to my buildTypes. It does not create a problem when set in the defaultConfig. I cannot say that I have any explanation for this as the documentation on versioning suggests it is okay, and even desirable.